# C++: Extern Object Circular Reference

Tags: c++, game-engine, extern, circular-dependency

I'm having issues declaring an external object in another object because of circular dependency. Consider the following:

The LevelEditor object contains an array of modules (all modules are children of editor_module):

```
#include "../Objects/editor_module.h"
#include "Modules/collisionGrid_module.h"
#include "Modules/HUD_module.h"
#include "Modules/IO_module.h"
#include "Modules/ledge_module.h"
#include "Modules/segment_module.h"

namespace g_editor
{
    class LevelEditor
    {
```

However the modules need to refer back to the editor to use its functions:

```
#pragma once

#include "../LevelEditor/LevelEditor.h"
extern g_editor::LevelEditor g_levelEditor;

namespace g_editor
{
    class editor_module
    {
```

On compilation, there are circular dependency issues. Is there a design consideration that I am overlooking?

Comment: Might want to look in forward declarations.

Comment: My understanding is that forward declarations do not allow for function access to declared objects

Comment: You include the header in the implementation file so you have access to functions but break the cyclic dependency. If you use inline it is not the right solution though.

Comment: Do you mean to add both LevelEditor.h and editor_module.h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the modules just need references to the class, then they don't need the complete class definition, just a forward declaration:

```
namespace g_editor {class LevelEditor;}
```

Any code, for example in the module's member functions, which needs the complete definition (e.g. to access members of it) will have to go in a source file, which inlcudes the header. But the module's class definition itself shouldn't need that.

Comment: Forward declaration only leads to the following error: invalid use of incomplete type. Is there a way around it, or am I still missing something?

Comment: @slippery_nipples: The module class definition itself shouldn't need the complete type (assuming it only declares references to the `LevelEditor`, as you imply it does). Some of its member functions might need the complete definition; as I said, those function definitions will have to go in a source file. You should only have problems if you try to put all the code in headers; I'd advise against doing that.

Comment: Ok, so for clarification, if editor_module uses a LevelEditor function like "addSegment(int x, int y)", I would need to include the source in editor_module.cpp?

Comment: @slippery_nipples: Yes, that's right. The .cpp file can include all the headers it needs, giving all its code access to the complete type. The header can't, because of the circular dependency.